# How to run test in new tab using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I have no javascript Web UI experience. I am using [Selenium IDE firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/) to repeat a set of actions like going to a website and clicking on a set of links. I am able to record this as a test and execute it successfully. However, the test runs in a new browser all the time. Is there any way to make it run in a new tab of the existing browser?